# How to convert TxtNation string to array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to convert this string to array:

```
id:5918351498722606 sub:001 dlvrd:001 submit date:1410311037 done date:1410311038 
stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:New HTTP Test TxtN
```

using something like `explode(" ", $string)` is not effective in this case. because it is possible that `text` can be long.

Comment: Ok so what do you expect? And why is explode not effective? As far as I know it is effective.

Comment: @Nick @Andreas I am expecting something like ```array('id' => '5918351498722606 ')``` when i will use explode then it will make array from ```text``` and i don't want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `preg_match_all()` to extract segments with a string:string(up to whitespace) will allow you to capture things like `submit date:1410311037`.  The only problem is that the text at the end may have spaces in it.  So to cope with this it extracts the end text specifilcally.

```
$string = 'id:5918351498722606 sub:001 dlvrd:001 submit date:1410311037 done date:1410311038 
stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:New HTTP Test TxtN';

preg_match_all("/(.*?):(.*?)\s/", $string, $matches);
$matches[2][count($matches[2])-1] =  trim(strrchr($string, ":"), ":");
$out = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
print_r($out);
```

output...

```
Array
(
    [id] => 5918351498722606
    [sub] => 001
    [dlvrd] => 001
    [submit date] => 1410311037
    [done date] => 1410311038
    [stat] => DELIVRD
    [err] => 000
    [text] => New HTTP Test TxtN
)
```

Comment: Although this relies on a hack to get the last value it does seem to be the correct solution.

Comment: used this answer and updated it little bit. Now it checks if entered correct string. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the only place a value can have multiple words is at the end of your string (otherwise the problem is insoluble without knowing the list of keys), you can use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to find all the `key:value` pairs using this regex:

```
(?:^|\s+)([^:]+):([^:]+$|[^\s]+)
```

This looks for

- the beginning of the line or some whitespace
- some characters which are not `:`
- A `:`
- Either some number of characters followed by end of line, or some number of non-whitespace characters

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/R0er7J/1)

```
$string = 'id:5918351498722606 sub:001 dlvrd:001 submit date:1410311037 done date:1410311038 
stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:New HTTP Test TxtN';
preg_match_all('/(?:^|\s+)([^:]+):([^:]+$|[^\s]+)/', $string, $matches);
$output = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 5918351498722606
    [sub] => 001
    [dlvrd] => 001
    [submit date] => 1410311037
    [done date] => 1410311038
    [stat] => DELIVRD
    [err] => 000
    [text] => New HTTP Test TxtN
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Z7bsI)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this what i want :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $string = "id:5918351498722606 sub:001 dlvrd:001 submit date:1410311037 done date:1410311038 
stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:New HTTP Test TxtN";

    $spF = explode(' ',$string);

    $phpArray = array();

    foreach($spF as $data){

        $sp = explode(':',$data);

        if(!empty($sp[0]) && !empty($sp[1])){

            $phpArray[$sp[0]] = $sp[1];

        }

    }


    var_dump($phpArray);


?>
```

[image]

Comment: This good but look at ```text``` there is just New. nothing else.

Comment: You want "New HTTP Test TxtN" as value?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in your example data the values after the `:` are either digits only, uppercase characters  only or words with spaces. If that is the case you might use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) checking for either of those cases:

```
([^:]+):([A-Z]{2,}|\d+|\w+(?: \w+)*)
```

That will match:

- `([^:]+)` Capture in a group 1+ times not a `:` using a negated character class
- `:` Match literally
- `(` Capturing group

  - `[A-Z]{2,}` 2 or more times an uppercase letter
  - `|` Or
  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\w+(?: \w+)*` Or 1+ times a word character followed by a repeated group that matches a space and 1+ times a word character
- `)` Close capturing group

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YxVxxD/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/K5YHu)

For example:

```
$str = "id:5918351498722606 sub:001 dlvrd:001 submit date:1410311037 done date:1410311038 
stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:New HTTP Test TxtN";
$pattern = '/([^:]+):([A-Z]{2,}|\d+|\w+(?: \w+)*)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
$res = array_combine((array_map("trim", $matches[1])), $matches[2]);

print_r($res);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [id] => 5918351498722606
    [sub] => 001
    [dlvrd] => 001
    [submit date] => 1410311037
    [done date] => 1410311038
    [stat] => DELIVRD
    [err] => 000
    [text] => New HTTP Test TxtN
)
```